# How to call a javascript function for a templated string containing date

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I'm new to Javascript and HTML. When I click on a button I get a pop up screen that should display date extracted from XML. Now, below is the code

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<table>    
<tr>
    <th>Posted on: </th>
    <td>function(){var myDate="{{posted}}";
       myDate=myDate.split("-");
       var newDate=myDate[0]+"/"+myDate[1]+"/"+myDate[2];
       return(new Date(newDate).getTime());}?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</script>
```

The date extracted is in the format (Y-m-d) like 2012-12-03 which has to be changed to 03-Dec-2013. I have done so far and when I click on the button the pop-up is not appearing. When I checked the console in firebug I see this error- `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name` . I cannot use any event function and the date should be displayed when i click this button. How can I do this?

Comment: That is a template. But I want to display date extracted from XML to be displayed within <tr> tags

Comment: you may want to separate the `javascript` and `html` code first. And give a name to your function for example `function displayDate()`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a date in the format yyyy-mm-dd, you can reformat it to dd-mmm-yyyy using something like:

```
function reformatDate(s) {
  var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',
                'Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
  var t = s.split('-');
  return t[2] + '-' + months[--t[1]] + '-' + t[0];
}
```

Which should be in a script element somewhere, or loaded from an external file. In the HTML you'll have something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Posted on: </th>
    <td id="myDate"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The somehow you get the value from the template into the page and use a function to put it into the table, maybe:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('myDate').innerHTML = formatDate('2013-12-12');
}
```

I don't know how you get the value from the XML and pass it to the function. It seems to me that if the XML is read at the server, it can write the value directly to the HTML. If it is accessed using AJAX from the client, then you can write it to the table in a callback rather than using *window.onload*.